# Issues with my Rig

Tags: modeling, rendering

All works great with my rig except the fingers, they rotate in sideways, I tried recalculate roll -Z and that did not help.

P.S. I use Auto Rig Pro plugin to generate my rig. Also to rotate my fingers into a fist I use individual origins and rotate them on Y axis.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Much appreciated!!!!

Pic info:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know Autorig Pro. But have you tried to adjust the bone rolls manually? You can do this in the N-panel. It's also helpful to activate the display of the bone axis (it's in the Viewport Display options IIRC). You might need to roll some control bones as well.